# How to get coordinates of Route/way using OSM/any other API

Tags: python, gis, openstreetmap

I am working with GPS coordinates and was using OSM API for python. I need to know if there is a way I can find out the coordinates of a route. For example if I enter starting and ending coordinates and OSM Generates a path. This path also have coordinates, so I want to extract these coordinates.

Any other suggestion using some other API(but for python only)?
Can google maps provide such info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [OSM Wiki about routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing).

There are various routing engines available for [online routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) and [offline routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers). Popular OSM-based routing engines are:

- [GraphHopper](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GraphHopper)
- [OSRM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Open_Source_Routing_Machine)
- [YOURS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS)
- [OpenRouteService](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService)
- [Valhalla](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Valhalla)

All of them can be used from a python project (or any other programming language).

Comment: thank you for your response, I have check graphhopper and OSRM but was not able to install OSRM, in linux that's why avoiding it. Although it was easy and exactly what i need to do. will try graphhopper.